# file_get_contents with empty file not working PHP

Tags: php, file, file-get-contents, fgets

I try to use file_get_contents form PHP but it's not working.

There is my code :

```
$filename = "/opt/gemel/test.txt";


if($filecontent = file_get_contents($filename)){

    $nom = fgets(STDIN);

    file_put_contents($filename, $nom, FILE_APPEND);
}
else
    echo "fail";
```

And my file **test.txt** is empty. (0 octets). He exists but he is empty.

When i write something into it, my code works perfectly but if he is empty my code echo "fails"

Why that, why he can't open the file **text.txt** ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The function `file_get_contents` returns the string that's in the file. If the file contains no data, then `file_get_contents` returns an empty string. If you would try to `var_dump('' == false);` you would get `true`. So, even though the file can be read, the contents of the file evaluates to `false`.

If you would use this line, your code should work:

```
if($filecontent = file_get_contents($filename) !== false){
```

Edit; link to the documentation of the [Comparison operators](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php).

Comment: you say **file_get_contents** return an empty string like a false. So this line **file_get_contents($filename) !== false** is supposed to be false, because file_get_contents return false. So why it's work and not echo "fail"?

Comment: It has to do with the types of the variables. file_get_contents returns `false` (a boolean) if it can't open the file, it returns `''` (a string) if it opens an empty file. The triple character comparison (`!==`) also checks if the types of the variables are the same. Please check the link to the documentation in my answer for more information.

Comment: Ok, I did not grasp the nuance between "type" and "equal to". Thank you for your explanations.