# How to check if a text file is empty in PHP?

Tags: php, file

How to check if a text file is empty in PHP?

I've tried what I found on the internet which is this:

```
if( '' != filesize('data.txt')){

    echo "The file is empty";
}
```

ALSO THIS:

```
if( 0 != filesize('data.txt')){

    echo "The file is empty";
}
```

And no of them seems to work.

Answer (score 14):

Simply use this first:

```
if (filesize('data.txt') == 0){
    echo "The file is DEFINITELY empty";
}
```

if still in doubt (depending what **empty** meaning to you), also try:

```
if (trim(file_get_contents('data.txt')) == false) {
    echo "The file is empty too";
}
```

Take a note on Niels Keurentjes, becareful as http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php said:

> Prior to PHP 5.5, empty() only supports variables; anything else will
>   result in a parse error. In other words, the following will not work:
>   empty(trim($name)). Instead, use trim($name) == false.

Comment: This will generate an E_WARNING if the file specified doesn't exist, so this should be wrapped in an is_file() call. `if ((!is_file ($filename)) || (0 === filesize ($filename)))`

Answer (score 4):

It should be this. You check if the filesize is 0. You're code asked if the filesize was different of 0 and then it was empty.

```
if ( 0 == filesize( $file_path ) )
{
    // file is empty
}
```

Comment: Then it's probably not a copmlete empty file and you can use the answer of [Niels Keurentjes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25638868/how-to-check-if-a-text-file-is-empty-in-php/25638904#25638904)

Answer (score 4):

First of all, equality is the `==` operator - you're doing the reverse check right now. But even then, emptiness isn't an absolute, you might run into a fake-empty text-file which actually has a newline or a UTF-8 BOM (byte-order mark).

```
if(filesize($path) < 16 && empty(trim(file_get_contents($path))) )
     die('This works by definition.');
```

Comment: What if `myfile.txt` will contain up to 2Gb of content ?

Comment: If that is a realistic scenario, and just checking for a 0-sized file isn't enough, you'll have to implement just reading the first handful of bytes with `fopen` and `fread`. Or add a `filesize` check which skips some assumptions there. Edited that in just to be complete.

Answer (score 1):

I use file_get_contents for small xml files.  The following code works for me, credit to Lex here, with explanation: [file_get_contents with empty file not working PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17615003/file-get-contents-with-empty-file-not-working-php/17615078)

```
if(file_get_contents($file) !== false) {
    echo 'your file is empty';
} else {
    echo 'file is not empty';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (file_get_contents($file_path) != "") {
    echo 'file is not empty';
} else {
    echo 'file is empty';
}
```

Comment: file_get_contents() will read the whole file so it  consume more disk I/O. filesize($path) is better

Comment: I put that:

if (file_get_contents('data.txt') != "")
and it's not working filesize either.

I prefer file_get_contents because my text file is small 5 or 6 KB

Answer (score 0):

```
The filesize() function returns the size of the specified file.

This function returns the file size in bytes on success or FALSE on failure.
```

*Example*

```
<?php
echo filesize("test.txt");
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If the file is empty, `filesize` will return `0` and we can use it as a `boolean`, something like:

```
$txtFile = "someFile.txt";
if( ! filesize( $txtFile ) )
{
    // EMPTY FILE
}
```

Comment: Actually it should be `IF NOT`. Like `if( !filesize( $txtFile ) )`

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple of options that build on the answer provided by [Niels Keurentjes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25638904/6600846) to check contents by size range. With these suggestions, if the file size is met its contents are "included" on the page.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php

Both check whether the file exists, then evaluate it based on size (in bytes). If file size is greater than or equal to 5 bytes, a success message is printed and the file contents are included. If the file is not found or is less than 5 bytes (effectively empty), an error message is shown and the file not included. On error, clearstatcache is effected to prevent the file result from remaining on page refresh. (I've tried functions with/without clearstatcache and it does help.)
http://php.net/manual/en/function.clearstatcache.php

The file itself can be entered:

```
As a string throughout: 'file.txt'
As a variable: $file = 'file.txt';
As a constant (per examples): define ('FILE', 'file.txt');
```

Option #1: Function

```
   <?php
    define ('FILE', 'file.txt');

    function includeFile() {
    if (file_exists(FILE))
    {
    echo 'File exists!' . '<br>';
    if (filesize(FILE) >= 5)
    {
    echo 'File has content!' . '<br>';
    include FILE;
    } else {
    echo 'File is empty.';
    clearstatcache();
    }
    }
    else {
    echo 'File not found.';
    clearstatcache();}
    }
    includeFile(); // call the function
    ?>
```

Option #2: If/Else Statement

```
<?php
define ('NEW_FILE', 'newfile.txt');

if (file_exists(NEW_FILE) && (filesize(NEW_FILE)) >= 5){
echo 'File exists and has content!' . '<br>';
include NEW_FILE;
}
else {
echo 'File not found or is empty.';
clearstatcache();
}
?>
```

The verifications can be removed:

```
echo 'File exists!' . '<br>';
echo 'File has content!' . '<br>';
echo 'File is empty.';
echo 'File not found.';
echo 'File exists and has content!' . '<br>';
echo 'File not found or is empty.';
```