# PHP how to return false with file() for an empty .csv file?

Tags: php, file, csv, fgetcsv

Why do I always get a array with one item of empty string for an empty .csv file?

```
$content = file('products.csv');

print_r($content);
```

result:

```
Array ( [0] => )
```

Can I return `false` so that I know there is nothing in the csv file?

Comment: Try [`filesize()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filesize.php) - `if (filesize('products.csv') == 0)`

Comment: The [`file()`](http://php.net/file) function doesn't know CSV. There are options for skipping empty lines however.

Comment: By adding some wrapping stuff...

Comment: You should also see http://stackoverflow.com/a/25638904/ - *"But even then, emptiness isn't an absolute, you might run into a fake-empty text-file which actually has a newline or a UTF-8 BOM."* - Not to mention some unicode characters which isn't mentioned in that Q&A.

Comment: You should use `fgetcsv()` to read CSV files instead of `file()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A single line test should get you the result:

`$empty = empty($content) || (count($content) === 1 && empty($content[0]));`

The following should avoid the "fake empty":

`$empty = empty($content) || (count($content) === 1 && $content[0] === '');`

If you need a re-usable function, and prefer, as you stated, to get an array or nothing, this may be helpful:

```
function get_file($file_name = null, $strict = false) {
    $return = null;
    if(!empty($file_name) && is_readable($file_name)) {
        $contents = file($file_name);
        if(
            !empty($contents)
            && (
                count($contents) > 1 
                || (
                    !empty($contents[0])
                    || ($strict && $contents[0] !== '')
                )
            )
        ) {
            $return = $contents;
        }
    }
    return $return;
}
```

I mean, we could get all kinds of creative and iterate over lines, etc.  But I think you get the idea.

If you want to get a CSV file, I would suggest using a method like `fgetcsv()` (repurposed):

```
function getcsv($file_name, $headers = array(), $delimiter = ',', $enclosure = '"', $escape = "\\" ) {
    $contents = array();
    $get_headers = $headers === FALSE;
    $headers = is_array($headers) ? array_values($headers) : array();
    if(!empty($file_name) && is_readable($file_name)) {
        $row = 0;
        if (($handle = fopen($file_name, "r")) !== FALSE) {
            while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 0, $delimiter, $enclosure, $escape)) !== FALSE) {
                if($get_headers && empty($headers)) {
                    $headers = $data;
                    continue;
                }
                foreach($data as $i => $col_value) {
                    $col_name = isset($headers[$i]) ? $headers[$i] : $i;
                    $contents[$row][$col_name] = $col_value;
                }
                $row++;
            }
            fclose($handle);
        }
    }

    return $contents;
}
```

Note, above is not tested, just a quick draft, and I am going to bed.  I'll edit it tomorrow if need be.

Finally, if you are getting a single line, with white-space, and this validates as "empty" in your eyes, simple test it after a trim:

```
$empty_line = trim($content[$line_num]) == '';
```

Not sure what else to tell you.  I think we have equipped you with quite a few tools and ways to validate this situation.  Best of luck.

Comment: thanks. but it does not work for me I'm afraid because for `var_dump($contentst[0]);` I always get `string '
' (length=2)`...

Comment: Added a check for white-space strings.

Comment: Only comment would be that you can only assume the first array key is going to be zero. `$contents[key($contents)]` would return the first entry in the array more safely

Comment: It isn't an assumption, `file()` will only return an `array` with an index starting at 0, or `false`.

Answer (score 4):

This seems like ad-hoc behaviour particular to your taste (no problem with that at all). Which means, you should probably create a wrapper function for this.

```
function contentIsNotEmpty($content) {
   $isEmpty = empty($content) || (count($content) == 1 && empty($content[0]));
   return $isEmpty ? false : $content;
}
```

EDIT: Incorporated @scrowler's feedback, and Michael J. Mulligan's.

Comment: Or better yet return false if its empty or return the contents if not e.g. `$contents = file($filename); return empty($contents) ? false : $contents;`

Comment: Agreed. This is more in line with what the OP asked.

Comment: @scrowler That will be invalid if the variable is an array with a single empty entry.  The array is no longer empty due to the fact that it has an entry. http://ideone.com/uwnNHG

Comment: @MichaelJMulligan fair enough - `return (empty($contents) || empty($contents[key($contents)])) ? false : $contents;`

Comment: @scrowler - What if only the first entry is empty, but there are 100 entries?

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$content = file('products.csv');
         if(!empty($content)){
          print_r();}{
        else{
           // Do something if no content
        }
```