# Determinate line file it´s empty in loop for

Tags: php, for-loop

The file called "file_changes.dat", it´s totally empty, no have any informations, and create in server, i use this script for simple show data from this file, the script it´s the next :

```
$fil_dat_changes=file("file_changes.dat");

$f_changes=fopen("file_changes.dat","w");

for($fh=0;$fh<sizeof($fil_dat_changes);$fh++) {

if(trim($fil_dat_changes[$fh])=="") 
{ 
print "NO DATA";
fputs($f_changes,"".date("dmYHis").""."\n"); 
}    
else 
{ 
print "YES EXISTS LINE"; 
}


}

fclose($f_changes);
```

And i don´t know why if file it´s empty, when i put :

> if(trim($fil_dat_changes[0])=="")

Don´t show nothing, and also don´t put the line with fputs, i think the result must show NO DATA ans insert the informations, but don´t insert nothing

I don´t understand which it´s the problem because i think if don´t exists any line of informations or data, must insert the line finally in the file

That´s it´s my question, why don´t insert data, thank´s in advance all community, regards

Comment: You should check what is in `$fil_dat_changes` to see what it will search through.  Alternatively, you could use [How to check if a text file is empty in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25638868/how-to-check-if-a-text-file-is-empty-in-php).

Comment: That file create from zero, no have any data inside, i try with filesize and all and also chech the line outside, but if i try determinate if line it´s empty when use fopen "w", show this problem, and never determinate the file it´s empty

Comment: Do you check the file size before using `$f_changes=fopen("file_changes.dat","w");`?

Comment: Yes right, if i try to test if file size it´s empty until use fopen, tell me right it´s empty, the problem it´s determiante is it´s open whe use fopen, and try run in loop the file, it´s as if the file if´it´s open with fopen "w" can´t determinate if it´s empty if until no have data insert

Answer (score 0):

You can check the file contains data using `filesize()`. BUT as you also open the file for writing in

```
$f_changes=fopen("file_changes.dat","w");
```

this will always empty the file and set it for writing.  This will clear any data already in the file.

If instead you check if the file is empty and then use `file_put_contents()` to write to the file, this will only do this if the file is empty...

```
if ( 0 == filesize( "file_changes.dat" ) )  {
    file_put_contents("file_changes.dat", date("dmYHis").PHP_EOL);
}
else    {
    echo "YES EXISTS LINE"; 
}
```

Comment: I fix the problem with this for($fh=0;$fh<=sizeof($fil_dat_changes);$fh++), the problem it´s i put <sizeof and change to <=sizeof(), never return 0 if dont´put =, regards

Comment: @Jose, when you run it with something in the file, does it empty the file afterwards?

Comment: Yes right if the file have something inside, detect without problem but if the file it´s totally empty the problem it´s if you put in loop fr sizeof<($file), never return if the file or line it´s empty, the trick it´s put in loop for , sizeof<=($file), with this equal, if file it´s empty, always in loop you can return 0 is line or file it´s empty

Comment: @Jose, also if you show warnings/notices, you will get `PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 0`.